# explanation on what this function does... mainly just the regular expressions

Tags: php, preg-match

Can someone give me a brief explanation on this:

```
function id_zero($id)
    {
    if (preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $id) && $id > 0) return $id;
    return 0;
    }
```

mainly just this part: `"/^[0-9]+$/"`

It's looking for a number in beteween 0 and 9 and i'm really not sure what the other characters are doing...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%2F%5E%5B0-9%5D%2B%24%2F

This will also help you with other regular expressions.

Comment: Nice website, thank you. Bookmarked.

Comment: http://regex101.com/ is another good resource.

Answer (score 1):

The function is looking to make sure the $id passed is just numbers, greater than 0. Otherwise it returns 0.

- `^` means start of the line (or `$id` in this case)
- `[0-9]+` means any number of digits
- `$` means the end of the line (or `$id` again in this case)
- the `/` are just used to specify that it's regex.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside notice, you can replace this function by:

```
function id_zero($id) {
    $a = intval($id);    
    return ((string)$a==$id)? $a : 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Matches a string of digits (one or more) between 0-9 from the start of the variable, $id, if its greater than 0 it returns the number, if not it returns 0. The "carat" signifies the beginning of the variable, or from the start of. the dollar sign is escaping it.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: "single digit"? I guess that `+` doesn't mean anything then.

Comment: the slash, upward arrow and the plus and dollar sign is really what confuses me.

Comment: oh. The "carat" signifies the beginning of the variable, or from the start of. the dollar sign is escaping it.

Comment: `$` signifies the end of the line, not escaping